# How to load right layout in emulator?

Tags: android, layout, emulation

I have two folder res/layout and res/layout-sw600dp. When I try to run my app in Tablet Emulator 7 inch (1024x600) I see on screen layout from res/layout. How to see another layout for tablet from layout-sw600dp in Emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the layout you want to open or choose a different setting from the drop down menus and the relevant layout will be loaded. e.g Nexus One, Nexus S etc

Add a custom layout in this menu if the defaults do not suit your devices.

To see these layouts at runtime you need to run your app on a device\emulator that matches the layout settings.

[image]

Comment: You are right. I delete all my old emulators and reset. And create new emulator. Now works!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see both layouts, you will need to use different Android Virtual Devices (AVD's), or in other words, a different Emulator.  The android documentation has a page dedicated to [managing AVD's](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html).

The android development team has provided a tool that you use to create AVD's called `AVD Manager`.  I believe that you have used it, because to be on an emulator means that you have already created one!

You can find it in Eclipse in the following location:

> Window -> AVD Manager

To actually *see* the different layouts between the different emulators, you will need to configure them differently, to accurately represent the device you want to target.  You should be able to tweak the Hardware options to make your emulators behave differently.  You can find a list of hardware options [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html).

Comment: OK, I have two different emulators. How to load in first emualator layout from res/layout and in second emulator layout from res/layout-sw600dp?

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I have added to my original answer what you should do to make your different emulators actually behave differently.

Comment: I know about this hardware options, but it is not work for me. May be I need hw.lcd.density? I set 320 from list, how to set 600 manually?